# Azure VMSS Deploy wpf

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to better understand azure virtual machine scale sets and how my company can use it. Currently we run a custom software (wpf program) that will need to be deployed and updated on all VMs.

Is a extension where I setup the deploy of the wpf?

Can I pull the files from a git repo to deploy?

How do I config this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not directly. there is a custom script extension and azure powershell dsc extension (and several others, like chef) which allow you to do pretty much anything, but nothing built-in
2. No, you cannot do that natively, you can use those extensions to do whatever you like. Or, better, you can use ci\cd systems (like Azure Devops) to do that. You need to install agent on the vm (in most cases) and then use that ci\cd system to deploy to vmss instances.
3. Another alternative - using images, that is a native way, but you need to prebuild images (packer, questionmark).

Comment: Azure Devops current hosts our repos so maybe that would be the best approach. Been working on it most the morning and still having trouble understanding it though.

Comment: you can use Azure Devops extension to install agent on vmss and you can use deployment groups in Azure Devops to target these.

Comment: two weeks later I am still running around chasing my tail. @4c74356b41 is there anyway we can screen share and you could walk me through it??? I will do anything at this point.

Comment: you can easily find my contacts online (from my blog, for example) or you can just create more specific questions here :)

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by your contacts

Comment: my email, for example